# How to remove part of a string

Tags: c#

I am saving a string into a database like Beginner A1.. Intermediate B2..UpperIntermediate etc and i need to display just the A1,B2, C1.

```
 grammarExNotes.Text = article.AmountOfGrammarDescription.ToString().Remove()
 grammarExNotes.Text = article.AmountOfGrammarDescription.ToString().Trim()
```

I am not very sure how to do this since if i use .Remove() i need to specify the starting point but as all my values have different starting point. Can you help please?

Comment: If you always have <word1> <word2> format, and you always want the word2 value then use: `article.AmountOfGrammarDescription.ToString().Trim().Split(" ")[1]`

Comment: x.Substring(x.Length - 2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find a fiddle link to test it https://dotnetfiddle.net/jsAkEr

```
grammarExNotes.Text = article.AmountOfGrammarDescription.ToString().Split(new[] {' '}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string desc = article.AmountOfGrammarDescription.ToString();
grammarExNotes.Text = desc.Substring(desc.Length - 2);
```